# Change process assigne in Activiti BPM 6.0.0.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, alfresco, business-process-management, alfresco-enterprise

We are trying to implement process reassign and are experiencing issues because database attribute START_USER_ID_ in table ACT_RU_EXECUTION isn't updated. After googling we have found out that IBatis execution does not support updating that filed through *updateExecution* action.

Github IBatis **updateExecution** definition is located [here](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/develop/activiti-engine/src/main/resources/org/activiti/db/mapping/entity/Execution.xml)

We know that Activiti fully supports reassigning tasks, but what about reasigning process instance while process instance does not have any active human tasks but process instance waiting let's say on timer event?